# InDesign pages to Illustrator art boards

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I have a multi-page document in InDesign, each page is a separate design that really should have been created in Illustrator instead. Is it possible to export each page from InDesign into Illustrator as art boards while preserving bleeds?
That last part is especially important, otherwise it's just a manual process of exporting a PDF, then importing individual PDF pages, then editing each AI document to add bleeds,  **and then** turning off clipping paths for every single object to get the bleeds where they need to be.

I'm hoping there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Found my own answer, so posting here for others:

1. In InDesign, export as EPS. In the dialog window that follows, there is a Bleed option. Set that to your current bleed width and export. Each page will be exported as a separate EPS file, but won't preserve artboard dimensions. The *art* will be the right size though.
2. In Illustrator, open the EPS file. Edit the artboard to the correct dimensions, and add the bleed.

It's still a little complex, but it sure beats having to release clipping masks on tons of separate objects.